# How to install pagespeed with already-built in nginx server

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

I have installed nginx in a DigitalOcean Droplet, following these guides:

[how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-16-04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-16-04)

[how-to-install-nginx-on-ubuntu-16-04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-nginx-on-ubuntu-16-04)

The PageSpeed [docs](https://www.modpagespeed.com/doc/build_ngx_pagespeed_from_source) give me 2 options to instal PageSpeed **Automated Install** and **Manual Install**

I choose Automated Install with to options:

`bash <(curl -f -L -sS https://ngxpagespeed.com/install) -v latest-stable -m`

Where the options mean:

```
-m, --dynamic-module  Build ngx_pagespeed as a dynamic module.
-v, --ngx-pagespeed-version <ngx_pagespeed version>
      What version of ngx_pagespeed to build.  Valid options include:
      * latest-beta
      * latest-stable
      * a version number, such as 1.11.33.4
```

I get:

```
ngx_pagespeed is ready to be built against nginx.
When running ./configure:
  Give ./configure the following arguments:
    --add-dynamic-module=/root/incubator-pagespeed-ngx-latest-stable

If this is for integration with an already-built nginx, make sure
to include any other arguments you originally passed to
./configure.  You can see these with 'nginx -V'.
```

next, I go for the other's arguments, `# nginx -V`

```
nginx version: nginx/1.12.1
built with OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --with-cc-opt='-g -O2 -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2' --with-ld-opt='-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -fPIE -pie -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -fPIC' --prefix=/usr/share/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --lock-path=/var/lock/nginx.lock --pid-path=/run/nginx.pid --modules-path=/usr/lib/nginx/modules --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/body --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/fastcgi --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/proxy --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/scgi --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/uwsgi --with-debug --with-pcre-jit --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_auth_request_module --with-http_v2_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_slice_module --with-threads --with-http_addition_module --with-http_geoip_module=dynamic --with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_image_filter_module=dynamic --with-http_sub_module --with-http_xslt_module=dynamic --with-stream=dynamic --with-stream_ssl_module --with-stream_ssl_preread_module --with-mail=dynamic --with-mail_ssl_module --add-dynamic-module=/build/nginx-aqArPM/nginx-1.12.1/debian/modules/nginx-auth-pam --add-dynamic-module=/build/nginx-aqArPM/nginx-1.12.1/debian/modules/nginx-dav-ext-module --add-dynamic-module=/build/nginx-aqArPM/nginx-1.12.1/debian/modules/nginx-echo --add-dynamic-module=/build/nginx-aqArPM/nginx-1.12.1/debian/modules/nginx-upstream-fair --add-dynamic-module=/build/nginx-aqArPM/nginx-1.12.1/debian/modules/ngx_http_substitutions_filter_module
```

Where I run this:

```
./configure --add-dynamic-module=/root/incubator-pagespeed-ngx-latest-stable --with-cc-opt='-g -O2 -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2' --with-ld-opt='-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -fPIE -pie -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -fPIC' --prefix=/usr/share/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --lock-path=/var/lock/nginx.lock --pid-path=/run/nginx.pid --modules-path=/usr/lib/nginx/modules --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/body --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/fastcgi --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/proxy --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/scgi --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/uwsgi --with-debug --with-pcre-jit --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_auth_request_module --with-http_v2_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_slice_module --with-threads --with-http_addition_module --with-http_geoip_module=dynamic --with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_image_filter_module=dynamic --with-http_sub_module --with-http_xslt_module=dynamic --with-stream=dynamic --with-stream_ssl_module --with-stream_ssl_preread_module --with-mail=dynamic --with-mail_ssl_module --add-dynamic-module=/build/nginx-aqArPM/nginx-1.12.1/debian/modules/nginx-auth-pam --add-dynamic-module=/build/nginx-aqArPM/nginx-1.12.1/debian/modules/nginx-dav-ext-module --add-dynamic-module=/build/nginx-aqArPM/nginx-1.12.1/debian/modules/nginx-echo --add-dynamic-module=/build/nginx-aqArPM/nginx-1.12.1/debian/modules/nginx-upstream-fair --add-dynamic-module=/build/nginx-aqArPM/nginx-1.12.1/debian/modules/ngx_http_substitutions_filter_module
```

search results for "nginx"

```
# find / -name "nginx"
/var/log/nginx
/var/lib/nginx
/etc/nginx
/etc/init.d/nginx
/etc/logrotate.d/nginx
/etc/ufw/applications.d/nginx
/etc/default/nginx
/usr/share/nginx
/usr/share/doc/nginx
/usr/sbin/nginx
/usr/lib/nginx
```

Comment: I don't think pagespeed is a dynamic module for nginx. Back when I was using pagespeed a couple of years ago, I had to do a custom build of nginx with pagespeed included. That very well may have changed, but I know that that path will work for you. Try following the "Build Instructions" section on the pagespeed docs you linked.

Answer (score 2):

Copy the configuration from `nginx -V` and also add *--add-dynamic-module=/root/incubator-pagespeed-ngx-latest-stable* to the configuration.

My final configuration:

```
--add-dynamic-module=/root/incubator-pagespeed-ngx-latest-stable --with-cc-opt='-g -O2 -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2' --with-ld-opt='-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -fPIE -pie -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now' --prefix=/usr/share/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --lock-path=/var/lock/nginx.lock --pid-path=/run/nginx.pid --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/body --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/fastcgi --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/proxy --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/scgi --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/uwsgi --with-debug --with-pcre-jit --with-ipv6 --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_auth_request_module --with-http_addition_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_geoip_module --with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_image_filter_module --with-http_v2_module --with-http_sub_module --with-http_xslt_module --with-stream --with-stream_ssl_module --with-mail --with-mail_ssl_module --with-threads --with-cc-opt='-DNGX_HTTP_HEADERS'
```

**Build Nginx with the above config**

```
cd
NGINX_VERSION=1.12.2
wget http://nginx.org/download/nginx-${NGINX_VERSION}.tar.gz
tar -xvzf nginx-${NGINX_VERSION}.tar.gz
cd nginx-${NGINX_VERSION}/
./configure --add-dynamic-module=/root/incubator-pagespeed-ngx-latest-stable --with-cc-opt='-g -O2 -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2' --with-ld-opt='-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -fPIE -pie -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now' --prefix=/usr/share/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --lock-path=/var/lock/nginx.lock --pid-path=/run/nginx.pid --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/body --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/fastcgi --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/proxy --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/scgi --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/uwsgi --with-debug --with-pcre-jit --with-ipv6 --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_auth_request_module --with-http_addition_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_geoip_module --with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_image_filter_module --with-http_v2_module --with-http_sub_module --with-http_xslt_module --with-stream --with-stream_ssl_module --with-mail --with-mail_ssl_module --with-threads --with-cc-opt='-DNGX_HTTP_HEADERS'
make
sudo make install
```

**Final step:**
Add `load_module "modules/ngx_pagespeed.so";` to the top of the nginx main configuration file.

**Reference:** https://www.modpagespeed.com/doc/build_ngx_pagespeed_from_source